# Making a https request using nodejs fails but works using curl

Tags: node.js, https

Any idea why this request would be failing in `nodejs` considering it works using `curl`? Maybe I've not mapped the request correctly.

Request using `curl` cli:

```
curl -u myusername:mypassword https://db.com/dbname/_all_docs
```

Response, the documents in db:

```
{
  rows: [
    ..
  ]
}
```

Request using `https` module in `nodejs`:

```
var requestOptions = {
  host: 'db.com',
  path: 'dbname/_all_docs',
  method: 'GET',
  auth: 'myusername:mypassword'
};
```

Response code is `502`:

```
{"error":"bad_gateway","reason":"Bad gateway"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `path` should start with a forward slash:

```
var requestOptions = {
  host: 'db.com',
  path: '/dbname/_all_docs',
  method: 'GET',
  auth: 'myusername:mypassword'
};
```